# Check JSON Value which comes dynamically from the Server

Tags: android, json

I have JSON Response like this.I have tried a lot but unable to parse the Values.

```
{
    "ResponseCode": "000",
    "ResponseDescription": "Successful",
    "SystemServiceID": [
        "4"
    ],
    "SystemServiceName": [
        "Test Name"
    ],
    "ProductID": [
        "10"
    ],
    "ProductName": [
        "Testing"
    ],
    "ProductDescription": [
        "Test product"
    ],
    "MinimumValue": [
        10000
    ],
    "MaximumValue": [
        500000
    ],
    "ImageURL": [
        null
    ],
    "Country": [
        "Test"
    ],
    "CompanyID": [
        "1"
    ],
    "CompanyName": [
        "Test"
    ],
    "FieldLevel": [
        "2"
    ],
    "FieldInfo": [
        "{\"Field1\":{\"Field Name\":\"Phone Number\",\"Field Type\":\"Number\",\"Validation\":{\"Min\":\"4\",\"Max\":\"8\"}},\"Field2\":{\"Field Name\":\"Email\",\"Field Type\":\"String\",\"Validation\":{\"Regular Expression\":\"aaaaa\",\"Min Length\":\"10\",\"Max Length\":\"20\"}}}"
    ]
}
```

I have the last field `FieldInfo` which have the Field1,Field2 which comes dynamically from the server means sometimes FieldInfo have 2 Fields or Sometimes 3 Fields or Sometimes it have 4 fields and so on.

If it have the 2 Fields then it should be Field1,Field2 
If it have the 3 Fields then it should be Field1,Field2,Field3 and so on.

**Code**

```
private ArrayList<BillPayProduct> parseBillPayResult(String data) 
    {
        try
        {
            final JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jsonArray;

            if(jsonObject.getString("ResponseCode").equals("000"))/*&&jsonObject.getString("ResponseDescription").equals("Successful"))*/
            {
                sysSerID=new ArrayList<String>();
                sysSerName=new ArrayList<String>();
                productID=new ArrayList<String>();
                productName=new ArrayList<String>();
                productDesc=new ArrayList<String>();
                minVal=new ArrayList<String>();
                maxVal=new ArrayList<String>();
                ImageURL=new ArrayList<String>();
                Country=new ArrayList<String>();
                CompanyID=new ArrayList<String>();
                CompanyName=new ArrayList<String>();
                FieldLevel=new ArrayList<String>();
                FieldInfo=new ArrayList<String>();

                if(jsonObject.has("SystemServiceID"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("SystemServiceID");

                    System.out.println("Length of systemserviceID:"+jsonArray.length()+"\ngetting System ServiceID");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        sysSerID.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("SystemServiceName"))
                {   
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("SystemServiceName");

                    System.out.println("Length of SystemServiceName:"+jsonArray.length()+"\ngetting System ServiceName");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        sysSerName.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("ProductID"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProductID");

                    System.out.println("Length of ProductID:"+jsonArray.length()+"\ngetting ProductID");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        productID.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("ProductDescription"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProductDescription");

                    System.out.println("Length of ProductDescription:"+jsonArray.length()+"\ngetting ProductDescription");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        productDesc.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    } 
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("BatchID"))
                {
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("BatchID");

                    System.out.println("length of BatchID:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting BatchID");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        batchID.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("MinimumValue"))
                {
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MinimumValue");

                    System.out.println("length of MinimumValue:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting MinimumValue");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        minVal.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("MaximumValue"))
                {
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MaximumValue");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        maxVal.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                        System.out.println(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("ProductName"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProductName");

                    System.out.println("length of productID:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting product name");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        productName.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                /*if(jsonObject.has("ProductType"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("ProductType");

                    System.out.println("length of productID:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting product Type");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        productType.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }*/
                if(jsonObject.has("ImageURL"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("ImageURL");

                    System.out.println("length of ImageURL:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting ImageURL");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        ImageURL.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("Country"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Country");

                    System.out.println("length of ImageURL:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting Country");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        Country.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("CompanyID"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("CompanyID");

                    System.out.println("length of CompanyID:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting CompanyID");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        CompanyID.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("CompanyName"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("CompanyName");

                    System.out.println("length of CompanyName:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting CompanyName");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        CompanyName.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("FieldLevel"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("FieldLevel");

                    System.out.println("length of FieldLevel:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting FieldLevel");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        FieldLevel.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }

                if(jsonObject.has("FieldInfo"))
                {
                    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("FieldInfo");

                    System.out.println("length of FieldInfo:"+jsonArray.length()+"\nGetting FieldInfo");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        FieldInfo.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    }
                }


                ArrayList<BillPayProduct> BillPayproductList=new ArrayList<BillPayProduct>();

                for(int i=0;i<productID.size();i++)
                {

                    BillPayProduct billpay_products=new BillPayProduct();
                    billpay_products.setSystemServiceID((String)sysSerID.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setSystemServiceName((String)sysSerName.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setProductID((String)productID.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setProductName((String)productName.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setProductDesc((String)productDesc.get(i)); 
                    billpay_products.setMinValue((String)minVal.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setMaxValue((String)maxVal.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setImageURL((String)ImageURL.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setCountry((String)Country.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setCompanyID((String)CompanyID.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setCompanyName((String)CompanyName.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setFieldLevel((String)FieldLevel.get(i));
                    billpay_products.setFieldInfo((String)FieldInfo.get(i));
                    //inserting product into Database.   
                    //inserting product into ArrayList
                    BillPayproductList.add(billpay_products);
                } 
                return BillPayproductList;
            }

        } 
        catch (final JSONException e) 
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Bean Class**

```
public class BillPayProduct extends Products
{
    String Country;
    String CompanyID;
    String CompanyName;
    String FieldLevel;
    String FieldInfo;

    public String getCountry() 
    {
        return Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) 
    {
        Country = country;
    }

    public String getCompanyID() 
    {
        return CompanyID;
    }

    public void setCompanyID(String companyID) 
    {
        CompanyID = companyID;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() 
    {
        return CompanyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) 
    {
        CompanyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getFieldLevel() 
    {
        return FieldLevel;
    }

    public void setFieldLevel(String fieldLevel) 
    {
        FieldLevel = fieldLevel;
    }

    public String getFieldInfo() 
    {
        return FieldInfo;
    }

    public void setFieldInfo(String fieldInfo) 
    {
        FieldInfo = fieldInfo;
    }
}
```

My Question is that how can i check that how many fields it have???
And how to parse it and stored ?

What is the most preferable way to store the those values?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance ... :)

Comment: i think u posted same question earlier ..post ur code plz

Comment: not sure but i think u need to know the fields of json before parsing the json

Comment: I want to know the length of fields before parsing and also the efficient way to store it.Like how to store the two filed in same container either in Hashmap or ArrayList or in any other container

Comment: create Bean Class and make arraylist<ur_class>

Comment: @Stacks28 I have already created Bean Class named BillPayProduct in which i have stored the FieldInfo as it is .Now i want to parse its details when m calling the getFieldInfo() method.I want to parse this Field Info details in getFieldInfo() method and it will return the dynamic fields value.Hope its clear.

Comment: ok i got it , can u change ur service for example if ur SystemServiceName dont have value return null instead then u wont be using this statement(if(jsonObject.has("SystemServiceName")))...make use ur json response patter remains contant in key...value may change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34138/discussion-between-stacks28-and-androidlearner)

Answer (score 0):

you can enumerate the keys of the root, for instance

```
Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
```

> What is the most preferable way to store the those values?

Tipically I create a read-only class, with the values I expect and I add it to a collection:

```
public class JSONDescriptor {
  public final String filed1;
  public final String filed2;

  public JSONDescriptor(String filed1, String filed2) {
       this.field1 = field1;
       this.field2 = field2;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONResponse);
String mResponseCode = jsonObject.getString("ResponseCode");
String mResponseDescription = jsonObject.getString("ResponseDescription");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SystemServiceID");
```

Within this jsonArray you have only one value.If it's like that we can't able to parse the value.
So,it should be like this format`"Id": "4"`(which means object and it's value) within jsonArray.
Otherwise, if it takes only one id then change it to `"SystemServiceID": "4"`this format and it can be parsed as mRsespoonseCode parsing technique.

thanks dude. If you have any queries pls add comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exactly way to parse your `JSON String` :

```
JSONObject mMainObj = new JSONObject(mMyResult);
if(mMainObj != null){
    String response = mMainObj.getString("ResponseCode"); // gets ResponseCode
    String desc = mMainObj.getString("ResponseDescription"); //gets ResponseDescription

    // SystemServiceID
    JSONArray mSysService = mMainObj.getJSONArray("SystemServiceID");
    if(mSysService != null){
        for (int j = 0; j < mSysService.length(); j++) {
            int mId = mSysService.getInt(j); // gets 4 and all other values, if there are some
        }
    }

    // SystemServiceName
    JSONArray mSysServiceName = mMainObj.getJSONArray("SystemServiceName");
    if(mSysServiceName != null){
        for (int j = 0; j < mSysServiceName.length(); j++) {
            String mName = mSysServiceName.getString(j); // gets Test Name and all other values, if there are some
        }
    }

    // The same for ProductID, ProductName and etc.

    JSONArray mFieldInfo = mMainObj.getJSONArray("FieldInfo");
    if(mFieldInfo != null){
        for(int j = 0; j < mFieldInfo.length(); j++){
            JSONObject mItem = mFieldInfo.getJSONObject(i);
            if(mItem != null){
                Iterator<Object> keys = mItem.keys();
                while(keys.hasNext()){
                    String id = String.valueOf(keys.next()); // This value represent Field1
                    JSONArray mField = mItem.getJSONArray(id);
                    if(mField != null){
                        for(int i = 0; i < mField.length();i++){
                            JSONObject mElem = mField.getJSONObject(i);
                            if(mElem != null){
                                String mFieldName = mElem.getString("Field Name"); // value: Phone Number
                                // and etc.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Didn't tested the code, there can be some typo mistakes, if it's not working correctly just post a comment and I will fix it.

Hope this helps! : )

Comment: @Andriod-Developer I hve created One Bean Class BillPayProduct which have the getters and Setters Methods.Now i want to parse the FieldInfo when m calling the getFieldInfo() method from the BillPayProduct Class.

Comment: I can't say nothing before I see your class and what he looks like.

Comment: I don't think you will need this class, but the way you can use it, it will be more complicated to create separated Strings from your JSON, give them to your class and you have to create different methods to parse every single JSON String. Check if my answer is working and parse the json as it should be, just use your response instead of `mMyResult` and put logs so you can see if the json is parsing correctly.

Comment: It show this error :: The method keys() is undefined for the type JSONArray on this line `Iterator<Object> keys = mFieldInfo.keys();`

Comment: My mistake sorry, it should be `JSONObject`, check the edited answer.

Comment: The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String) on this line `JSONArray mField = mFieldInfo.getJSONArray(id);`

Comment: replace `mFieldInfo` with `mItem` .